# How can I replace text with angle bracket without parsing the replace value?

Tags: xslt, xquery

I have this:

```
replace("Both cruciate ligaments are well visualized and are intact.", 
        ".", 
        ".&lt;br&gt;")
```

But I do not want to output the escaped angle brackets but the actual brackets. when I run the code I get :

```
Both cruciate ligaments are well visualized and are intact.&lt;br&gt;
```

I want:

```
Both cruciate ligaments are well visualized and are intact.<br>
```

How can I achieve that? I cannot use the angle bracket directly as replace value since I get an error.

---

### EDIT

I have a stylesheet that takes in a text file that is injected into a HTML file (coming from the stylesheet). I take an XML (Clinical document) and a text file and merge them together with the stylesheet. So for example I have:

> RADIOLOGY REPORT 
>   NAME: JOHN, DOE 
>   DoB: 1982-02-25 
>   
>   Injected text goes here

The text has to wrap on carriage return and has to wrap at a word level. I did manage to do the latter but I did not find a way to the line breaks. I thought of finding 'LF' in the file an replace with <BR> so that once the page is rendered I get to see the line breaks.

Comment: Depending on your implementation, whatever is displaying this text will likely unescape the angle brackets.

Comment: Do you want to replace a literal dot `.` with a `<br/>` element? Or any character? I wonder whether your sample with the second argument of the `replace` call does not need to escape the dot as `'\.'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `xsl:analyze-string` if you want to output nodes and not simply strings. Here is an example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:template match="text">
  <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\.">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/><br/>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With the input being

```
<text>Both cruciate ligaments are well visualized and are intact.</text>
```

the transformation result is

```
Both cruciate ligaments are well visualized and are intact.<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Martin Honnen's answer is a perfectly good way to do this.

Using a simple template to find the text in question is another way:

```
<xsl:variable name="magic-string"
  select='"Both cruciate ligaments are well visualized and are intact."'/>
...
<xsl:template match="text()
  [contains(.,$magic-string)]">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(.,$magic-string)"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$magic-string"/>
  <br/>      
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(.,$magic-string)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

In either case, use the HTML output method to serialize the empty `br` element as `<br>` instead of as `<br/>`.

Note: I'm assuming here that you want a `br` after this particular sentence, not that you want one after each occurrence of full stop, which is how Martin Honnen appears to have interpreted the question.

Comment: Really clever! Yes, I need a search and replace in a text file.